# iPhone, Object allocated and stored into 'glossPath' is not referenced later (object leaked)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have this warning in analyzer and also in leaks instrument, how can I fix this leak?

*Object allocated on line 86 and stored into 'glossPath' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)*

Tnx

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are responsible for releasing the object returned by `CGPathCreateMutable()` as per ["The Create Rule"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). It is also stated in the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateMutable):

> **Return Value**
>
> A new mutable path. You are responsible for releasing this object.

You can use `CGPathRelease()` to release the path.

```
CGPathRelease(glossPath);
```

Comment: tnx could you have a look also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968521/iphone-allocations-problem